# NRPE Python script output bug

Tags: python, nagios, nrpe

I have been tasked with making a custom python script (since i'm bad with Bash) to run on a remote NRPE client which recursively counts the number of files in the /tmp directory. This is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import os
import subprocess
import sys
file_count = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk("/tmp")]) #Recursive check of /tmp




if file_count < 1000:
        x = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'OK -', str(file_count), 'files in /tmp.'], stdout=subproce$
        print(x.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")) #Converts from byteobj to str
#       subprocess.run('exit 0', shell=True, check=True) #Service OK  - exit 0
        sys.exit(0)

elif 1000 <= file_count < 1500:
        x = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'WARNING -', str(file_count), 'files in /tmp.'], stdout=sub$
        print(x.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")) #Converts from byteobj to str
        sys.exit(1)
else:
        x = subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'CRITICAL -', str(file_count), 'files in /tmp.'], stdout=su$
        print(x.communicate()[0].decode("utf-8")) #Converts from byteobj to str
        sys.exit(2)
```

**EDIT 1:** I tried hardcoding `file_count` to `1300` and I got a WARNING: `1300 files in /tmp`. It appears the issue is solely in the nagios server's ability to read files in the client machine's `/tmp`.

What I have done:

- I have the script in the directory with the rest of the scripts.
- I have edited `/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg` on the client machine with the following line:

  ```
  command[check_tmp]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_tmp.py
  ```
- I have edited this `/usr/local/nagios/etc/servers/testserver.cfg` file on the nagios server as follows:

  ```
  define service {
          use                             generic-service
          host_name                       wp-proxy
          service_description             Files in /tmp
          check_command                   check_nrpe!check_tmp

  }
  ```

The output:
correct output is: `OK - 3 files in /tmp`

- When I run the script on the client machine as root, I got a correct output
- When I run the script on the client machine as the nagios user, I get a correct output
- My output on the Nagios core APPEARS to be working, but it shows there are 0 files in `/tmp` when I know there are more. I made 2 files on the client machine and 1 file on the nagios server.

The server output for reference:

https://puu.sh/BioHW/838ba84c3e.png

(Ignore the bottom server, any issues solved with the wp-proxy will also be changed on the wpreess-gkanc1)

**EDIT 2:** I ran the following on the nagios server:

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 192.168.1.59 -c check_tmp_folder
```

I indeed got a 0 file return. I still don't know how this can be fixed, however.

Comment: Does the nagios user or the user NRPE is running under have permissions to read the directory?  Can you run the script as the user on the remote server and get the expected results?

`su nagios -c "/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_tmp.py"`

Comment: Yes, running the above command on the remote server I get the desired output

Comment: /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H 192.168.1.59 -su nagios -c check_tmp_folder


Running this on the Nagios server (not host), gives me a wrong output. It even gives me the wrong output when i replace -su nagios with -su root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

Solution:

- Go to your systemd file for nrpe. Mine was found here:

  ```
  /lib/systemd/system/nrpe.service
  ```
- If not there, run:

  ```
  find / -name "nrpe.service"
  ```

and ignore all system.slice results

- Open the file with vi/nano
- Find a line which says `PrivateTmp=` (usually second to last line)
- If it is set to true, set it to false
- Save and exit the file and run the following 2 commands:

  ```
  daemon-reload
  restart nrpe.service
  ```

Problem solved.

Short explanation: The main reason for that issue is, that with debian 9.x, some processes which use systemd forced the private tmp directories by default. So if you have any other programs which have issues searching or indexing in `/tmp`, this solution can be tailored to fit.

Answer (score 0):

systemd service file, maybe this var is set to true :)

`PrivateTmp=` Takes a boolean argument. If true, sets up a new file system namespace for the executed processes and mounts private `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` directories inside it that is not shared by processes outside of the namespace.

This is useful to secure access to temporary files of the process, but makes sharing between processes via `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` impossible. If this is enabled, all temporary files created by a service in these directories will be removed after the service is stopped. Defaults to false. It is possible to run two or more units within the same private `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` namespace by using the JoinsNamespaceOf= directive, see systemd.unit(5) for details.

This setting is implied if `DynamicUser=` is set. For this setting the same restrictions regarding mount propagation and privileges apply as for `ReadOnlyPaths=` and related calls, see above. Enabling this setting has the side effect of adding Requires= and After= dependencies on all mount units necessary to access `/tmp` and `/var/tmp`.

Moreover an implicitly After= ordering on systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service(8) is added. Note that the implementation of this setting might be impossible (for example if mount namespaces are not available), and the unit should be written in a way that does not solely rely on this setting for security.

Comment: It is nice that start with an answer, but please format it, such that it isreadable.